# How to upload pdf/images/document file together with form details(name,age,email) using http.post?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to submit a form using ionic 4 to php api backend with a form that contain name, age, email, and a document(pdf,image,word). Im stuck when trying to include the file into the http post.

already try with file transfer but the plugin is deprecated

```
async OncreatePerson() { 
    let formData  = {
      name: this.name,
      email: this.email,
      age: this.age,
      phone: this.phone,
    };
      const Url = 'http://localhost/api.php';
      const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        })
      };
    this.http.post(Url, JSON.stringify(formData ), httpOptions);
  }
```

can someone show me some example of code to work with this problem

Comment: Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-uploader, I have an app running https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload, even thought I'm on Angular 6.

Comment: do you have any example on submitting both file and the form together?